# Show Count on top of the bar graph - ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

In my options object in Chart.js

I've tried

```
plugins: {
    afterDatasetsDraw: function (context, easing) {
        var ctx = context.chart.ctx;
        context.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                if (dataset.data[i] != 0) {
                    var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                    var textY = model.y + (dataset.type == "line" ? -3 : 15);

                    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                    ctx.textAlign = 'start';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                    ctx.fillStyle = dataset.type == "line" ? "black" : "black";
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.translate(model.x, textY-15);
                    ctx.rotate(4.7);
                    ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], 0, 0);
                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I got no luck.

---

Although, I've tried this, it works

```
animation: {
    duration: ,
    onComplete: function() {
        var chartInstance = this.chart,
        ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
            var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
            meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                var data = dataset.data[index];
                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

It seems to get what I want, but when I hover on it, it blinks and seem very buggy.

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz4NX.gif

**Do you guys know a better way ?**

Comment: "show count"? Do you talk about 2685 for example? (The first chart - left red bar for example) - if not maybe add more details. Very easy to implement this idea using `chartjs-plugin-datalabels`: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/

Comment: Yes, I talked about `2685`.

Comment: I tried your link, I see label now :) , but it stay on top ... and too close. Do you know ow to make it look good ? https://i.imgur.com/2OkgNgn.png

Comment: See the example below. In general, in your case, you should decrease font size, offset, padding and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution by **datalabels plugin** - https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/ and this **options** for labels:

- `anchor:'end',` ==> highest element boundary
- `align: top` ==> the label is positioned after the anchor point, following the same direction

For small tuning, change `padding`, `offset` (Negative or positive), font-size and so on (A lot of control). [datalabels Options](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/options.html#scriptable-options)

**"Hello world example":**

```js
// Change default options for ALL charts
Chart.helpers.merge(Chart.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels, {
  formatter: function(value, context) {
    return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  },
  opacity: 1,
  color: 'black',
  borderColor: '#11469e', 
  anchor: 'end', /*https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/positioning.html */
  align: 'top', /* https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/positioning.html#alignment-and-offset */
  font: {
    weight: 'bold',
    size: 14,
    lineHeight: 1 /* align v center */
  },

  offset: 0, /* 4 by deafult */
  padding:{
    bottom: 0 /* 4 by deafult */
  }
});

var data = {
  labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "America"],
  datasets: [{
    /* data */
    label: "Population (millions)",
    backgroundColor: ["#490A3D", "#BD1550","#E97F02", '#F8CA00'],
    data: [1000,1500,2000, 2200]
  }]
};

var options = {
  plugins: {
    // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
    datalabels: {
    }
  },
  animation:{
    duration: 2000 /* time in ms */
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return '$' + value;
        }
      },
      stacked: true
    }]
  }
};

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>
```

One more example (Extra hover and styling):
https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/bGdYaLd

`datalabels` is very cool library. For example, add `$` and change `1000` to `1,000` to data in 2 lines of code.

```
formatter: function(value, context) {
 return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
},
```

Related: [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: Is this line correct ? `plugins: {
    // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
    datalabels: {
    }
  },`

Comment: Are you telling us to do it ? or just left comment for us to know what you did ?